# Python - Mechanize : Why does it need CookieJar?

Tags: python, browser, mechanize, web-scraping

In mechanize, we have :

method : `set_cookiejar()`

But, why do we need a cookie jar anyway, when we say that mechanize has automatic cookie handling ?

Please help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't *need* one -- if you don't specify one, Mechanize will just handle it. You might want to use cookies you have already stored in a jar, or save cookies in a jar for use with other scripts, so Mechanize lets you specify one.

Comment: Thanks.. it was driving me nuts.